# Нужно из отсканированного TIFF изображения получить JPG в php imagick

Tags: php, imagick

Есть отсканированное TIFF изображение с параметрами 16bit, 14000px X 14000px, 1200dpi. В php imagick делаю:

```
$im->readImage( $DOCUMENT_ROOT.$TifFilePath );  
$im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_ZIP);
$im->setCompressionQuality(10);
$im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
```

Получаю файл с изображением тех же линейных размеров и разрешения. Размер файла порядка 40 мб. Нужно уменьшить размер выходного файла на порядок, пусть даже ценой ухудшения качества изображения. Линейные размеры и разрешение должны сохраняться.

Comment: Милая, вы ж его зипуете, а не джепгуете.  $comression_type = Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG;

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setcompressionquality.php. RTFM!

Comment: upvote бикоз астрономов надо уважать  и да, человек может и ошибся где-то в коде (и мы знаем где), но выдал пример, ограничивающие параметры и правильные теги и это не запрос для "а как мне задачу решить", а что-то для работы важное. Когда Луна упадет тебе на голову и Солнце и все метеориты начнут тебя избивать, спасут тебя только вот эти вот они (и Элон Маск) и дева Мария и дух Королева и святой Ослик.

Comment: Мне без разницы, зип или джеп, при использовании Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG результирующий файл получается еще больше. setCompressionQuality в коде, если вы видите, я применяю, но даже если я поставлю там 1, файл получается аналогичного размера и качества. upvote, а где ошибка в коде?

Comment: Упс! невнимательно прочитала. Попробую Imagick::setImageCompressionQuality().

Comment: Спасибо! С setImageCompressionQuality() все получилось, как надо!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте изменить размер изображения, или проскалировать его:

```php
        $imagick = new \Imagick;

        $imagick->setResolution(200,200); 

        $imagick->readImage($file);

        $imagick->scaleImage(1920,0);

        $imagick->setImageFormat('jpeg');
        $imagick->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
        $imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(55);

        $imagick->writeImages($path.$filename, false);

        $imagick->clear(); 
        $imagick->destroy();
```